# How to do sorting in dynamic content of table in jsp,struts2?

Tags: jsp, sorting

I am new to do this sorting technique in jsp page of dynamic content. My application is integrated with struts2+jsp+hibenate. I am using the following code in jsp.

report.jsp

```
          <table class="report_view_table" id="results">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th width="35" scope="col" abbr="no">No
            </td>
            <th width="50" scope="col" abbr="status">Date
            </td>
            <th width="80" scope="col" abbr="option">productName
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <s:if test="resultList.size() > 0">
  <s:if test="productName.size() > 0">
  <s:iterator status="rowNo" value="resultList">
      <s:set name="Result_product" value="%{productId}" />
  <tr> <td><span class="check"><s:property value="%{#rowNo.count}" /></span></td>
       <td><span class="check"><s:property value="%{proDate}" /></span></td>
       <td><span class="check"><s:iterator value="productName"> 
           <s:set name="product"value="%{productId}" /> 
           <s:if test="%{#product== #Result_product}">
        <s:property value="%{productionName}" /> </s:if></s:iterator>
       </span></td>
   </tr>
   </s:iterator>
   </s:if>
   </s:if>
   <s:else>No report is available
   </s:else>
    <s:else>No report is available
   </s:else>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Here, i want to sort the table by its column heading. how to sort this dynamic content of table. Anybody please help me to do this functionality. **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: jquery datatable will be the best option

Comment: @HemantMetalia: thank for your quick reply. Any specified URL is for to do this with jquery. Is there no option to use javascript/ajax for this process? Please share the URL for jquey datatable. Need to do sorting in client side not in server side.

Comment: see my post for link and details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client side sorting** :  [use jquery dataTable](http://datatables.net/)

for using jquery datatable specify the id of you table to the jquery datatable.
e.g. results is the id of your table

add javascript file for the jquery and jquery datatable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#results').dataTable();
});
```

**Server Side sorting** :  sort you list resultList on server side using Arrays.sort() by help of interface Comparable refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: http://yoast.com/articles/sortable-table/ URL provide a good solution for sorting in dynamic table of JSP.

Comment: Thank you. I was used fully javascript only so this helps me quick to use. If u know about pagination like twitter/facebook in javascript please send the URL. I tried with full of javascript with 1,2, at the bottom but twitter/facebook like pagination don't know. If u have any idea related to that please share. Thanks in advance.